# How do I scan for Wireless Access Points?

Tags: wireless, 11.10

In Ubuntu 11.04 I used InSSIDer to scan the available APs and sort them by signal strength.

Unfortunately the program seems to be broken in Ubuntu 11.10, and

```
iwlist wlan0 scan
```

doesn't return anything meaningful.

What options do I have to scan for available Wireless Access Point, possibly with a GUI?

Comment: Ubuntu release? Hardware? Environment? "anything meaningful"? Should I have to install 11.04 and InSSIDer to find out what behaviour you're looking for? What does "seems to be broken" really mean? Please help us help you by including information in your questions. "Options"? Try Network Manager. You should find its icon in the top row.

Comment: If you read it more carefully everything is already there. I use ubuntu 11.10, and inssider doesn't launch at all. I use intel wifi. I want to list all the available networks, sorted by strength.

Comment: `sudo  iwlist wlan0 scanning | egrep 'Cell |Encryption|Quality|Last beacon|ESSID'` should help.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning | egrep 'Cell |Encryption|Quality|Last beacon|ESSID'` should help.

It's the combination of `sudo` (run as root, do privileged operations), `iwlist wlan0 scanning` (produce some output on STDOUT), the pipe symbol "|" (connecting STDOUT of the command(s) to the left to the STDIN of the process on the right), and an `egrep` command with a "single quoted" (to prevent the shell from interpreting the "|" characters) Regular Expression to filter STDIN. See `man bash`, `man sudo`, `man iwlist`, `man egrep`, and `man re_format` for details.

ALWAYS do man whatever (as above) BEFORE you execute a command string from someone else. Self-education is much safer than blind trust.

Comment: Could you please include an explanation of that command?

Comment: Could you please include the explanation in your question instead so that others can find it easier and benefit from it. Reason I asked for an explanation is to make your answer as complete as possible.

Comment: You might, optionally, want to add that it's very easy to search in man pages using `/`. Many new Linux users are scared of the size of man pages and their inability to find the correct information quickly.

Comment: This command doesn't need explanation.  The question isn't about pipes or manpages.  Some prerequisite knowledge must be assumed, otherwise most answers on this site will have to start with instructions for opening a terminal.

Answer (score 23):

## Using `iw`

I don't have `nm-tool` installed so I use [`iw`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iw).

This command sorts access points by signal strength, strongest first:

```
sudo iw wlan0 scan | grep -Po '(signal|SSID):\K.*' | sed 's/ $/ [unknown SSID]/' | paste -d ' ' - - | cut -c2- | sort -gr
```

### Each command explained:

#### `iw wlan0 scan`

Scan for access points reachable via interface `wlan0`.

#### `grep -Po '(signal|SSID):\K.*'`

Grep gets the text after "signal:" or "SSID:". See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673287/how-to-remove-a-word-prefix-using-grep/56236273#56236273) to learn more about the used options and `\K`.

Reduces the output of `iw wlan0 scan` to something like this:

```
 -77.00 dBm
 nameOfAccessPoint1
 -69.00 dBm
 
 -71.00 dBm
 nameOfAccessPoint2
```

Note that the access point with signal strength -69 dBm doesn't broadcast an SSID, the output of grep is a single space on that line.

#### `sed 's/ $/ [unknown SSID]/'`

To make the fact that the SSID is unknown explicit, we replace the single space with  `[unknown SSID]`. The output of `sed` is:

```
 -77.00 dBm
 nameOfAccessPoint1
 -69.00 dBm
 [unknown SSID]
 -71.00 dBm
 nameOfAccessPoint2
```

#### `paste -d ' ' - -`

With [paste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paste_(Unix)) we join two consecutive lines with a space in between. This produces:

```
 -77.00 dBm nameOfAccessPoint1
 -69.00 dBm [unknown SSID]
 -71.00 dBm nameOfAccessPoint2
```

#### `cut -c2- | sort -gr`

With `cut -c2-` we remove the leading space and `sort` orders the lines by dBm, smallest numerical value first. Which means the access points are sorted by signal strength, strongest first.

```
-69.00 dBm [unknown SSID]
-71.00 dBm nameOfAccessPoint2
-77.00 dBm nameOfAccessPoint1
```

---

### Alternatively

Here's another way to get access points sorted by signal strength. Mind that this command does not take care of access points with an empty SSID:

```
sudo iw wlan0 scan | egrep "signal:|SSID:" | sed -e "s/\tsignal: //" -e "s/\tSSID: //" | awk '{ORS = (NR % 2 == 0)? "\n" : " "; print}' | sort -gr
```

### Each command explained:

#### `iw wlan0 scan`

Scan for access points reachable via interface `wlan0`.

#### `egrep "signal:|SSID:"`

Get the lines with signal strength and the SSIDs from `iw`'s output. The output looks like this now:

```
        signal: -77.00 dBm
        SSID: nameOfAccessPoint1
        signal: -71.00 dBm
        SSID: nameOfAccessPoint2
```

#### `sed -e "s/\tsignal: //" -e "s/\tSSID: //"`

We reduce `egrep`'s output to this:

```
-77.00 dBm
nameOfAccessPoint1
-71.00 dBm
nameOfAccessPoint2
```

#### `awk '{ORS = (NR % 2 == 0)? "\n" : " "; print}'`

Bring the signal strength and the SSID on the same line. More specifically, when the line number (`NR`) is even, i.e., we are on a line showing an access point, the output record separator (`ORS`) should be a line break. Otherwise, we are on the line containing signal strength, so we join the line by making `ORS` a simple space.

#### `sort -gr`

If we `sort` this output by numerical value (`-g`) and reverse it (`-r`), we end up with a list of signal strengths and access points, showing the access point with the strongest signal on top:

```
-71.00 dBm nameOfAccessPoint2
-77.00 dBm nameOfAccessPoint1
```

---

Beware: Some access points can have an extended capability:

```
    Extended capabilities:
             * SSID List
```

This means grepping "SSID:" instead of "SSID" helps avoiding this extra output which would make the command fail otherwise.

Comment: Piping `grep` to `sed` to `awk`, don't you just love Linux! Very nice comprehensive answer. I know I'm not supposed to write a complimentary comment but this really deserves one, you even included intermediate output.

Answer (score 6):

```
nm-tool | grep "Freq.*Strength" | sed -ne "s|\(.*Strength \([0-9]\+\).*\)|\2}\1|p" | sort -n -r
```

1. Use output of `nm-tool` to get list of Wireless Access Points
2. Filter to get access points only
3. Use `sed` to append signal level in front of each line
4. sort output as numbers in reverse order (largest first)

`nm-tool` is part of "network-manager" package that is obviously installed in a typical Ubuntu system.

Comment: Thanks!  This command helpfully provides a concise and complete summary of all the APs in range.  The iwlist command seems to change dynamically from run to run based on current wifi activity; it also seems to fail when too many wifi APs are reporting at once.

Comment: answer is good for 2013. now, `nm-tool` was long replaced by `nmcli`

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [nmcli](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/nmcli.1.html), I found it myself a few months back and it's the easiest one I've used so far.

```
nmcli device wifi
```

Example output:

```
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID                             MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
        18:7B:CB:42:EF:8E  FRITZ!Box 7530 MS                Infra  11    260 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2      
*       D1:12:C8:87:D7:F1  FRITZ!Box 7530 MS                Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  75      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
        DD:72:2D:64:04:C9  example network                  Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  65      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 
        2C:A1:F2:9E:97:2E  FRITZ!Box 7530 MS                Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
        11:22:F5:89:71:9C  some_other_network               Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  55      ▂▄__  WPA2
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can install software on your machine, I would recommend [wavemon](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/wavemon/wavemon.1.en).

To install it run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wavemon
```

To run it:

```
sudo wavemon
```

Then press <kbd>F3</kbd> for the scan window. You should see something similar to this:

[image: wavemon scan window]

Answer (score 1):

## With `wpa_cli`

Using [`wpa_cli`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/wpa_cli.8) , which is part of [`wpa_supplicant`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/wpa_cli.8), you can get information about local Wi-Fi networks:

```
sudo wpa_cli scan && sudo wpa_cli scan_results
```

Example output:

```
Selected interface 'wlp3s0'
bssid / frequency / signal level / flags / ssid
23:99:21:91:89:34   2462    -50 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]   SSID_8
42:5d:25:a2:f5:7a   2462    -59 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]   SSID_7
21:99:94:b1:89:3b   5180    -54 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]   SSID_6
52:7d:2d:96:f4:d9   5500    -67 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]   SSID_5
54:7d:3d:a6:f4:c0   2412    -52 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]   SSID_4
9d:34:16:a0:04:81   2437    -53 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]   SSID_3
e9:40:e2:b3:58:dd   2412    -64 [WPA-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][ESS]    SSID_2
4a:5d:25:72:f5:79   5580    -72 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]   SSID_1
```

Answer (score -2):

```
iwinfo wlan0 scan
```

wlan0 is you wireless interface

the result like below list
...

```
Cell 06 - Address: F0:B4:29:50:76:0C
          ESSID: "Xiaomi_760B"
          Mode: Master  Channel: 1
          Signal: -38 dBm  Quality: 70/70
          Encryption: mixed WPA/WPA2 PSK (TKIP, CCMP) 
....
```

the command will return encryption info

system : openwrt 15.05