# How to search for wireless networks?

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, intel-wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I tried with this

```
sudo iwlist eth0 scan
```

but this doesn't seem to work :(..It says "interface dosn't support scanning"
What to do? Please help..
I can't access Internet on Ubuntu.

Even I've mobile broadband usb, but even that doesn't get detected. Other pendrives get detected

More details

```
*-network UNCLAIMED 
description: Network controller 
product: Broadcom Corporation 
vendor: Broadcom Corporation 
physical id: 0 
bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0 
version: 01 
width: 64 
bits clock: 33MHz 
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list configuration: latency=0 resources: memory:c1500000-c1507fff
```

And more details: 
lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Thames XT/GL [Radeon HD 7600M Series]
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4365 (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Please follow this question to install the driver first. The answer is dependent on the kernel version. To know your kernel version you can execute `uname -a`

[Broadcom 4365 wireless driver with 3.4 / 3.5 kernel](https://askubuntu.com/q/178352/35775)

---

`eth0` is not wireless adapter. It is Ethernet adapter.

Try `sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning | egrep 'Cell |Encryption|Quality|Last beacon|ESSID'`

Better, first enable wireless adapter using hardware switch.

then click on top panel `network manager` button to see the available networks.

Related:

[How do I scan for Wireless Access Points?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75625/35775)

Comment: It says "interface doesn't support scanning"

Comment: even this doesn't work: cd /sys/class/net/wlan0/wireless/

Comment: edit your question and include result of `sudo lshw -c network`,  `lsmod` and `rfkill list all`

Comment: *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Broadcom Corporation
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c1500000-c1507fff

Comment: 0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: yes
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: yes

Comment: you don't have intel wireless card. you have broadcom. That makes everything invalid, please post result of `lspci` so that we can help. Edit your question to include the result don't post as comment.

Comment: updated my answer.